# Empty Facebook friends list

Tags: meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-friends

So I'm using the "Facebook-sdk" plugin. I'm initializing Facebook like this:

```
FB.init({ appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true, status: true });

    FB.login(function(){ // get permissions
    }, {scope: 'user_friends, read_friendlists, user_photos, email, publish_actions  '});

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) { // to generate AccessToken
      if (response.authResponse) {
        console.log('LoginStatusResponse: ' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
      } else {
        console.log('AuthResponse: No');
      }
    });
```

Then in response to a button click event, I'm doing:

```
'click #get_fb_friends' : function(event, template) {

    FB.api( 
      "/me/friends",
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log('GOT them !!!' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
          return response;
        } else {
          console.log('No can do' + JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
        }
      });
  }
```

The thing is that I'm getting an empty Data variable:

```
GOT them !!!{
    "data": []
}
```

PS: The query `"/me"` returns all information about myself, it's the `"/me/friends"` that doesn't work.

Can it be a permissions problem ?

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m#answer-23417628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Wampie said, the API has changed, so you could try to use the v1 API (keep in mind that you'll need to request a new access token).

And you can still invite friends to your app by using the `apprequests` method.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'You should learn more about the Platform.'
}, function(){
  console.log(arguments);
});
```

Example here:
https://www.fbrell.com/fb.ui/apprequests

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has changed its api a few weeks ago,you can only access a list of your friends when they have personally accepted to use your app.. Nothing to do about it

Comment: But how can I invite them then to use my application if I can't select them ?